# Push Notifications with SQL Database

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-web-api

I recently started gathering information about push notifications with WebApi particularly from this article:

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/native-html5-push-notifications-with-asp-net-web-api-and-knockout-js/

I kinda want to use this method but I don't seem to get how to do this with Database. For example I want to get notification whenever a row is inserted in certain table. Is there a way to do this or I don't get things fully about its functionallity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events) and you may understand to getting events from database change events. Then you can tie it up to your push notification service.